# Glide время истечение годности кеша

Tags: java, android, glide

В своем андроид приложении для загрузки изображений(.gif)  использую glide. Изображение которые загружает глайд часто меняются но из-за кеширование очень долго изменение не заметны. Можно решить эту проблему отключением кеширование но этим я жертвую трафиком и при нестабильном интернете он не сможет вывести из кеша старую версию изображение. 
1. Сколько времени годен кеш в Glide (Срок годности кеша)?
2. Можно ли установить срок годности кеша?
3. Какой оптимальный вариант приняли бы вы?

Comment: было бы неплохо, если бы вы указали версию Glide, которую используете.

Comment: @mit Здравствуйте версия 4.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, можно по таймеру или при обновлении картинок, вручную чистить кэш:

Чистим оперативную память (если используется):

```
// Этот метод вызывать в main thread.
Glide.get(context).clearMemory();
```

Чистим дисковый кэш (если используется):

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Этот метод вызываем в background thread.
    Glide.get(applicationContext).clearDiskCache();
    return null;
  }
}
```

Подробнее о КЭШе в Glide v4 можно почитать в [офф. документации](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html).